i get the error Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
whenever i try uploading a photo in my form using flutter i get this error
Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
am new to flutter so i used an already made project and modified it

                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 8,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Photo',
                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .bodyMedium!
                                  .copyWith(
                                color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                letterSpacing: 0.1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 9,
                            ),

                            photoUrl != null ? Container(
                                height: 250,
                                width: double.infinity,
                                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                ),
                                child: Image.network(
                                  photoUrl ?? 'https://imgv3.fotor.com/images/blog-cover-image/part-blurry-image.jpg' ,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                )): const Text("Photo not selected yet"),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: AppColors.tabGrey,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () async{

                                FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                                  type: FileType.custom,
                                  allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
                                );

                                String id = uuid.v1();

                                if (result != null) {
                                  File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
                                  log(file.path);
                                  String fileName = result.files.single.name;

                                  Future result2 = storage.createFile(
                                    bucketId: Credentials.PhotosBucketId,
                                    fileId: id,
                                    file: InputFile.fromPath(
                                      path: file.path,
                                    ),
                                  );

                                  result2.then((response) {
                                    log("Pic Uploaded");
                                    photoUrl = 'https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/storage/buckets/${Credentials.PhotosBucketId}/files/${id}/view?project=${Credentials.ProjectID}';
                                    setState(() {});
                                    Dialogs.showSnackbar(context, "Picture updated successfully! Update to save");
                                  }).catchError((error) {
                                    print(error.response);
                                    Dialogs.showSnackbar(context, "${error}");
                                  });
                                } else {
                                  // User canceled the picker
                                  Dialogs.showSnackbar(context, "Unable to upload canceled in between");
                                }
                              },
                              child: Text("Upload Image", style: textTheme.titleSmall!.copyWith(color: AppColors.grey),),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            TextFieldInput(
                              controller: phoneController,
                              title: 'Phone',
                              hintText: 'Phone number',
                              onChanged: (val) {},
                            ),

                            opens != ""
                                ? Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'Last Updated',
                                        style: Theme.of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .bodyMedium!
                                            .copyWith(
                                              color:
                                                  Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                              letterSpacing: 0.1,
                                            ),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        height: 12,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Available: ${opens}",
                                        style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                                            color: Colors.deepPurple[700]),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Not Available: ${closes}",
                                        style: textTheme.bodyMedium!
                                            .copyWith(color: AppColors.orange),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                : const SizedBox(),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 25,
                            ),

                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                List arr = currentAddress.split(", ");
                                print(arr[arr.length - 1]);
                                print(arr[arr.length - 2]);
                                print(arr[arr.length - 3]);
                                if(ShopModel == null){
                                  print("check your information again");
                                }

                                else{
                                  if (myCurrentShop != null) {
                                    myCurrentShop!.name =
                                        storeNameController.text;
                                    myCurrentShop!.lat = lat;
                                    myCurrentShop!.long = long;
                                    myCurrentShop!.country = arr[arr.length - 1];
                                    myCurrentShop!.pincode = arr[arr.length - 2];
                                    myCurrentShop!.district = arr[arr.length - 3];
                                    myCurrentShop!.photo = photoUrl;
                                    myCurrentShop!.address = currentAddress;

                                    myCurrentShop!.phone = phoneController.text;

                                    myCurrentShop!.about = aboutController.text;
                                    myCurrentShop!.opens = opens;
                                    myCurrentShop!.closes = closes;
                                    myCurrentShop!.isOpen = isOpen;
                                    Dialogs.showLoaderDialog(context, "Saving");
                                    await APIs.instance
                                        .updateShopInfo(myCurrentShop!)
                                        .then((value) {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    });
                                  } else {
                                    ShopModel newShop = ShopModel(
                                      name: storeNameController.text,
                                      lat: lat,
                                      long: long,
                                      country: arr[arr.length - 1],
                                      pincode: arr[arr.length - 2],
                                      district: arr[arr.length - 3],
                                      photo:photoUrl,
                                      address: currentAddress,

                                      phone: phoneController.text,

                                      about: aboutController.text,
                                      opens: opens,
                                      closes: closes,
                                      isOpen: isOpen,
                                    );
                                    await APIs.instance
                                        .createShop(currentShop: newShop);}

                                  }
                              },
                              child: Text("Update Details"),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                          ]),
          ),
        ));
  }

thanks in advance
i tried adding attributes to appwrite and givingany permissions but it didnt work
and trying to upload a photo more than one time gives this error
Storage bucket with the requested ID could not be found., code: 404, type: storage_bucket_n

It would help if you said which line that error was triggering in.
